# C# LINQ question about creating temporary list while performing query

Tags: c#, linq

I am learning LINQ basics now and some question occurred. For example, I have an integer list -

```cs
var s = [3, 4, 5, 6, 1]
```

And I cannot understand why I can perform this query without errors:

```cs
s.Select((val, ind) => new { value = val, index = ind })
```

In `List<int>` we do not have access to indexes and how lambda function in `Select` statement understands that `ind` is an indexer?

Comment: What do you mean by "in `List<int>` we do not have access to indexes"?

Comment: "how lambda function in Select statement understands that `ind` is an indexer?" Well, how does anything know what anything means? How does `Console.WriteLine` know to print a line to the console? Short answer: They are designed and implemented this way.

Comment: `Select` can count. If I start feeding you an unknown number of items one at a time, you can tell me how many items you have received, right? I'm not sure why you think you don't have access to indexes with `List<T>` though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

because it is mentioned in the `Select` method declaration in the `Enumerable` class clearly.

```
//   selector:
//     A transform function to apply to each source element; the second parameter of
//     the function represents the index of the source element.

public static IEnumerable<TResult> Select<TSource, TResult>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, int, TResult> selector);
```